# Где здесь ошибка синтаксиса?

Tags: yii2

```
PHP Parse Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)'
```

in D:\sites\site\yii2\backend\controllers\SiteController.php:216
Stack trace:#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()#1 {main}

на строке 216 "else"

```
 Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return $result;
         } else {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException ('Only Post is allowed');
          }
```

```html
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use yii\base\DynamicModel;
use vova07\imperavi\Widget;
use yii\base\Action;
use yii\base\InvalidCallException;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\FileInput;
use common\models\Person;
use common\models\ImageManager;




/**
 * Site controller
 */
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                        'allow' => true,
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout', 'index','save-redactor-img','save-img'],
            
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }



public function actionSaveRedactorImg ($sub='main')
 {
        $this -> enableCsrfValidation = false;
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $dir = Yii::getAlias ('@images') .'/'.$sub.'/';
        if (!file_exists($dir)){
            FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
        }


        $result_link = str_replace('admin.','',Url::home(true)).'uploads/images/'.$sub.'/';
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('file');
        $model = new DynamicModel (compact ('file'));
        $model ->addRule ('file', 'image')->validate();

        if ($model->hasErrors()) {

            $result = [
            'error' => $model -> getFirstError ('file')
            ];
        } else {
              $model->file->name = strtotime('now').'_'.Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(6) . '.' . $model->file->extension;

            if ($model->file->saveAs ($dir . $model->file->name)) {
              $imag = Yii::$app->image->load($dir . $model->file->name);
                $imag -> resize (800, NULL, Yii\image\drivers\Image::PRECISE)
                ->save($dir . $model->file->name, 85); 
 
                $result = [
                'filelink' => $result_link . $model->file->name,'filename'=>$model->file->name];

        } else {

            $result = [
            'error' => Yii::t ('vova07/imperavi', 'ERROR_CAN_NOT_UPLOAD_FILE')
            ];

        }
        $model->save();
    }
             Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            return $result;
             } else {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException ('Only Post is allowed');
              }
         }
     


 public function actionSaveImg ()
     
        {

        $this -> enableCsrfValidation = false;
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

        $dir = Yii::getAlias ('@images') .'/'.$post['ImageManager']['class'].'/';
        if (!file_exists($dir)){
            FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
        }


        $result_link = str_replace('admin.','',Url::home(true)).'uploads/images/'.$post['class'].'/';
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('ImageManager[attachment]');
        $model = new ImageManager();
        $model->name = strtotime('now').'_'.Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(6) . '.' . $file->extension;
        $model =load($post);
        $model->validate();

         if ($model->hasErrors()) {

            $result = [
            'error' => $model -> getFirstError ('file')
            ];
        } else {
           if ($file->saveAs ($dir . $model->name)) {
              $imag = Yii::$app->image->load($dir . $model->name);
                $imag -> resize (800, NULL, Yii\image\drivers\Image::PRECISE)
                ->save($dir . $model->name, 85); 
 
                $result = [
                'filelink' => $result_link . $model->name,'filename'=>$model->name];

        } else {

            $result = [
            'error' => 'ошибка'
            ];

        }
    

      Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            return $result;
             } else {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException ('Only Post is allowed');
              }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Лишнее закрытие фигурной скобки перед `Yii::$app->response->format`. Если бы равномерно отбивали отстутпы, заметили бы без проблем.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Перед `Yii::$app->response->format`  кавычка не лишняя.  Ошибка в строке:    $model =load($post);

Answer (score 1):

***Для первоначальной редакции***

Перед public function actionSaveImg () уберите лишний закрывающий тег **}**. Также у вас ещё в самом конце файла лишний **}**.

Совет: используйте, например, PhpStorm или другой IDE, в них встроена функция форматирования кода. Так вы сможете сразу увидеть где и что у вас не так.

Comment: нет, не в этом ошибка..